# Return unique_ptr member variable from proxy class with operator()

Tags: c++, std

I would like to make a wrapper class (in this case a not null check, but it could be other checks).

Is there any way to extract member variable through `operator()` that would make it possible to *move* out the member variable. The use case is a `std::unique_ptr<>`

This is the use case

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct S {
    int x = 0;
    S(int x): x(x) {}
};

template <typename Type>
class NotNull
{
public:
    NotNull(Type value): m_value(std::move(value)) {}

    operator Type&() // <--------------------------------- this is the question
    {
       assertIsNotNull();
       return m_value;
    }


    typename std::pointer_traits<Type>::element_type *get() {
        return m_value.get();
    }

    private:
    void assertIsNotNull() {}

    Type m_value;
};
```

And this is what needs to work

```cpp
// Test code
int main() {
    {
        NotNull<S *> x {new S{10}};
        auto y = x; // This works
        delete y;
    }

    {
        NotNull<std::shared_ptr<S>> x{std::make_shared<S>(10)};
        auto y = x; // This works
    }
        
    {
        NotNull<std::unique_ptr<S>> x{std::make_unique<S>(10)};
        S* y = x.get(); // This does work, and needs to work as expected
                        // that is _not_ move the member
    }

    {
        NotNull<std::unique_ptr<S>> x{std::make_unique<S>(10)};
        auto y = std::move(x); // This copies the whole class
    }

    {
        NotNull<std::unique_ptr<S>> x{std::make_unique<S>(10)};
        std::unique_ptr<S> y = std::move(x); // <----------------- This does not work
    }
}
```

The compiler seems to not understand that I want to convert to a unique_ptr inside of the std::move call.

```c
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = S; _Dp = std::default_delete<S>]'
   57 |         std::unique_ptr<S> y = std::move(x); 
      |
```

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/bYMfc5)

Is it possible to use a class as a proxy for std::unique_ptr somehow and get this kind of syntax for moving out member variables.

PS. As you might have guessed I cannot rely on for example gsl::not_null, because this functionality does not exist there to my knowledge. DS.

Comment: You could write partial specializations `NotNull<T*>`, `NotNull<std::shared_ptr<T>>` and `NotNull<std::unique_ptr<T>>` and add special behavior in that way.

Comment: So how would you write that specialization for std::unique_ptr. Even when not considering the other ones i do not get the std::unique_ptr version to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler understands that you want to convert to a unique_ptr& (i.e Type&) just fine. The problem arises when you assign the result of that conversion to your local unique_ptr object: since its an lvalue reference, the compiler tries to invoke the copy constructor (not the move constructor, which requires an rvalue reference), but since unique_ptr deleted its copy constructor, you get the error.

What you probably wanted to do in that line is to convert to a unique_ptr&& (i.e an rvalue reference). To do that, you can overload your conversion operator based on [ref-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions):

```
operator Type&() & // converts to lvalue ref if invoked on lvalue
{
   assertIsNotNull();
   return m_value;
}

operator Type&&() && // converts to rvalue ref if invoked on a temporary
{
   assertIsNotNull();
   return std::move(m_value);
}
```

This way, the conversion operator will convert to the same type of reference that it was invoked on (i.e lvalue of used from a normal variable, and rvalue if used on a temporary or moved object).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference qualifiers to make separate versions of a member function depending on whether the object is an lvalue or rvalue reference, like so:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int x = 0;
    S(int x): x(x) {}
};

template <typename Type>
class NotNull
{
public:
    NotNull(Type value): m_value(std::move(value)) {}

    operator Type&()
    {
    assertIsNotNull();
    return m_value;
    }

    auto get() &
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue \n";
        return m_value.get();
    }

    auto get() &&
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue \n";
        auto retval =  m_value.get();
        m_value.release();
        return retval;
    }

    private:
    void assertIsNotNull() {}

    Type m_value;
};

int main()
{
    {
        NotNull<std::unique_ptr<S>> x{std::make_unique<S>(10)};
        S* y = x.get(); // This does work, and needs to work as expected
                        // that is _not_ move the member
    }
    {
        NotNull<std::unique_ptr<S>> x{std::make_unique<S>(10)};
        std::unique_ptr<S> y = std::unique_ptr<S>(std::move(x).get());  // Is this what you want?
    }
}
```